# No wireless networks shown on Kubuntu Plasma 5

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, kde

I recently got a new laptop and am setting up linux on it. I'm running off of a liveusb for Kubuntu (the new Plasma 5), and don't see (in the desktop UI) any support for wifi. The network manager shows only two tickboxes, one for wifi and one for airplane mode; nothing I do can get it to see the local wireless.

However, I was able to connect to an unencrypted AP by doing things manually:

```
# iwconfig wlan0 essid <AP name>
# dhclient wlan0
```

and am using the resulting connection to post this. The network manager icon, however, is still red, says "disconnected" when I hover over it, and doesn't show any AP's even though I'm clearly connected to one. The wireless card is:

```
# lspci -v
09:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev c3)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
        <snip>
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

I can't check the network manager with anything else as this laptop doesn't have an Ethernet adapter.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Why did you get KDE Plasma 5? That's beta and experimental software. KDE Plasma 5 is still being worked on and is not stable enough for use by end users (you).

Answer (score 2):

Sure, but I had similar problems on the old version of KDE. However, after poking around a bit with rfkill, I found the problem.

This machine is an HP Omen, and for some reason the OS incorrectly detected it as an Acer machine and loaded the acer-wmi module. This, in turn, thought that the wifi was always disabled, and listed an unremovable soft-block on an "acer-wireless" object.

Doing

```
# rmmod acer-wmi
```

fixed the problem.

Now the (Kubuntu with KDE4) installer is hanging, but I have to figure that out separately...

Comment: I just upgraded and my wifi setting in the toolbar didn't display any networks at all.  I had to run `sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi` but the idea stands.  Thanks